# Debugging an iPad device crash with little info

Tags: objective-c, ipad, debugging, objective-c++

I'm getting the following stack trace from an iPad crash pulled from the device.  This was pulled from a user's iPad and I don't know what they were doing when it crashed.  How would I get more info on why/where the app is crashing and fix it?

```
Uncaught C++ Exception
Stack trace:

   0 - 0   MyApp                               0x00005ac1 _Z16TerminateHandlerv + 24
   1 - 1   libstdc++.6.dylib                   0x33814e3d _ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE + 52
   2 - 2   libstdc++.6.dylib                   0x33814e91 _ZSt9terminatev + 16
   3 - 3   libstdc++.6.dylib                   0x33814f61 __cxa_throw + 84
   4 - 4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3441dc8b objc_exception_throw + 70
   5 - 5   Foundation                          0x3645192b __NSThreadPerformPerform + 654
   6 - 6   CoreFoundation                      0x34e16a79 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
   7 - 7   CoreFoundation                      0x34e1875f __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 382
   8 - 8   CoreFoundation                      0x34e194eb __CFRunLoopRun + 230
   9 - 9   CoreFoundation                      0x34da9ec3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
  10 - 10  CoreFoundation                      0x34da9dcb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
  11 - 11  GraphicsServices                    0x339d041f GSEventRunModal + 114
  12 - 12  GraphicsServices                    0x339d04cb GSEventRun + 62
  13 - 13  UIKit                               0x33a07d69 -[UIApplication _run] + 404
  14 - 14  UIKit                               0x33a05807 UIApplicationMain + 670
  15 - 15  MyApp                               0x000036af main + 70
  16 - 16  MyApp                               0x00003664 start + 40
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things you might try:
Somtimes apps crash and the debugger stops on a completely different method. Enable "guard malloc" in the xcode run settings (under schemes in xcode4), run the app in the debugger utill it crashes, and see if that shows you which method is to blame.

If not, your best bet is to run the app in the debugger and make the crash happen. Try everything, simulate memory warnings everywhere, use every feature of the app, try every possible combination of paths through the app. Asking the user what they think they were doing might narrow it down some.